# Putting breaks into a text written on a image

Tags: php, image, gd, php-gd

If i write a text on a picture with code below, code tries to type all the text in one line. So text overflows out of the image like in picture1. I want to write it like in picture2.

If there is a function in php which enables writting like in picture2 what is it?
If there is no function to do that, how can i do it by writting my code? Can you give me a clue?

```
$text = $_POST['text']; // Text comes from a form.

$im = @imagecreate(700, 350)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagettftext($im, 22, 0, 5, 25,  $text_color, 'fonts/COOLVETICA RG.TTF', properText($text));
imagepng($im, 'image.png');
```

> Picture1:

[image: Picture one]

---

> Picture2:

[image]

Comment: you will have to take a measurement based on the font-size and image width and set the chars per line dynamically

Comment: @DevZer0 Then this function splits the words. How can i prevent it?

Comment: GD is a VERY simplistic library. If you want linebreaks, you'll have to do put them in yourself, by calling the text function repeatedly with different string chunks and draw coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a bounding box using `imagettfbbox()` then the text will wrap. There's a full example on php.net:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php